# Pyspark transpose grouped Data Frame

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

i have a Spark data frame like this:

```
+------------------+--------------+
|             group|         words|
+------------------+--------------+
|               one|         word1|
|               one|         word2|
|               one|         word3|
|               two|         word4|
|               two|         word5|
|               two|         word6|
|             three|         word7|
|             three|         word8|
|             three|         word9|
+------------------+--------------+
```

I want to "transpose" to below form:

```
+------+-------+-------+--------+
| group|    one|    two|   three|
+------+-------+-------+--------+
|      |  word1|  word3|   word7|
| words|  word2|  word4|   word8|
|      |  word3|  word5|   word6|
+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

pivot() functions seems not to work beacause there is no column to aggregate. The first columns is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collect_list` then explode it with `inline` and `arrays_zip`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = (df.groupby(F.lit('words').alias('group'))
      .pivot('group')
      .agg(F.collect_list('words'))

pivot_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x != 'group']

# Pyspark v3.4.0+
df = df.select('group', F.inline(F.arrays_zip(*pivot_cols)))

# <Pyspark v3.4.0
df = df.select('group', F.expr(f"inline(arrays_zip({','.join(pivot_cols)}))"))
```

**UPDATE:**

If `group` includes some special characters, modify this line to wrap column name in ``.

```
pivot_cols = [f'`{x}`' for x in df.columns if x != 'group']
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine in this simple example, but when i have group names that contains dash (like group-1) it gives me error, do you know how to fix it? It seems like some function divides this name for two parts: group and 1 and then doesn't find group-1

Comment: I updated the answer, could you try it?